# bookmark not working in nested menusubitem shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to bookmark a double nested menusubitem in shinydashboard, however this is not working (see example below).

When you bookmark page 1, page 2 or page 3.1, then it is working smoothly. However, when you try to bookmark page 4.1.1, then it opens on page 1.

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- function(request){
    dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard Demo")
        , dashboardSidebar(
            sidebarMenu(
                # Setting id makes input$tabs give the tabName of currently-selected tab
                id = "tabs"
                , menuItem("Page 1", tabName = "page1", icon = NULL)
                , menuItem("Page 2", tabName = "page2", icon = NULL)
                , menuItem("Page 3", icon = NULL
                           , menuSubItem("Page 3.1", tabName = "page3_1", icon = NULL)
                )
                , menuItem("Page 4", icon = NULL
                           , menuItem("Page 4.1", icon = NULL
                                         , menuSubItem("Page 4.1.1", tabName = "page4_1_1", icon = NULL)
                           )
                )
            )
        )
        , dashboardBody(
            bookmarkButton()
            , tabItems(
                tabItem("page1", div(p(h2("Page 1"), "working", br(), "try to bookmark 4.1.1 and you will see it is not working")))
                , tabItem("page2", div(p(h2("Page 2"), "working")))
                , tabItem("page3_1", div(p(h2("Page 3.1"), "working")))
                , tabItem("page4_1_1", div(p(h2("Page 4.1.1"), "not working with bookmark button")))
            )
        )
        , title = "Dashboard example"
        
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

enableBookmarking(store = "url")
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It works fine for me.  Perhaps you may need to update your packages or RStudio.

Comment: Hi, YBS, sorry for the very late reply. I just installed the newest version of R (4.1.0) and shinydashboard (0.7.1) and its is still not working? When I bookmark page '4.1.1' and open this bookmark on another tab, I was guided to page 1 (instead of page 4.1.1).